# Creating SeekBar smaller than default?

Tags: android, height, seekbar

In my App,I have a very busy layout and I have to add some `SeekBars` to it.So I need to decrease `height` of seekbars.I serach in Google and in other questions in stackoverflow,but I could not find any solution,except of using`android:padding = "0dp"`,but it is not sufficient.I use this in my layout:

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:minHeight="0dip"
                android:maxHeight="2dip" />
```

You can see that I have used `maxHeight` and `minHeight`,but it seems that is effected by layout manager.How I can retrieve smaller SeekBar?

Comment: you have to use thumb and ProgressDrawable attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use these two property to make your desire seekbar

```
 android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
 android:thumb="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

and use small images for both of properties.